# How to multiply an Eigen Tensor by the scalar sum of another Eigen Tensor in C++?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, eigen, blas, tensor

I am using the Tensor aspect of the [Eigen](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen) library in C++ and would like to compute the element-wise product of one Eigen Tensor multiplied by the scalar sum of the elements in a second Eigen Tensor. Something like:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
Eigen::Tensor<float,2>u(5,5);
Eigen::Tensor<float,2>v(5,5);

u.setConstant(1.f);
v.setConstant(2.f);

Eigen::Tensor<float,2>ans(5,5);
ans = u*v.sum();
```

However the * operator is not supported in this way.

The [README](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/677c9f1577810e869f4f09881cabc3e503a810c1/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/README.md?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#markdown-header-tensor-typescalar) suggest to use the `.constant()` method associated with Tensor objects. And while

```
 ans = u*u.constant(5.);
 auto ans2 = u.sum();
```

compiles and functions properly

```
ans = u*u.constant(v.sum());
```

does not.

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Eigen::Tensor<float, 2>::constant(const Eigen::TensorReductionOp<Eigen::internal::SumReducer<float>, const Eigen::DimensionList<long int, 2ul>, const Eigen::Tensor<float, 2>, Eigen::MakePointer>)’
       ans = u*u.constant(v.sum());
                                 ^
```

From further reading it appears that this is because `u.constant()` expects a Scalar value to be passed to it, whereas `v.sum()` returns a "non-evaluated expression" (see **Tensor Operations and C++ "auto"** in [README](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/677c9f1577810e869f4f09881cabc3e503a810c1/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/README.md?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#markdown-header-tensor-typescalar)). There is further suggestion that evaluation of `v.sum()` can be forced using `.eval()`, though this appears to return another "non-evaluated expression" type, albeit with a `ForcedEvalOp` tagged on the end.

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Eigen::Tensor<float, 2>::constant(const Eigen::TensorForcedEvalOp<const Eigen::TensorReductionOp<Eigen::internal::SumReducer<float>, const Eigen::DimensionList<long int, 2ul>, const Eigen::Tensor<float, 2>, Eigen::MakePointer> >)’
   ans = u*u.constant(v.sum().eval());
                                    ^
```

The TODO section of [README](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/677c9f1577810e869f4f09881cabc3e503a810c1/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/README.md?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#markdown-header-tensor-typescalar) mentions:

"**Representation of scalar values:**
Scalar values are often represented by tensors of size 1 and rank 1. It would be more logical and user friendly to use tensors of rank 0 instead. For example Tensor::maximum() currently returns a Tensor. Similarly, the inner product of 2 1d tensors (through contractions) returns a 1d tensor. In the future these operations might be updated to return 0d tensors instead."

Which implies that `v.sum()` should return a rank 1 Tensor of length 1. But the `()` operator, typically used for indexing seem unable to access its value in a usable form for `u.constant()` and:

```
ans = u*u.constant(v.sum()(0))
```

also fails to compile.

```
 error: no match for call to ‘(const Eigen::TensorReductionOp<Eigen::internal::SumReducer<float>, const Eigen::DimensionList<long int, 2ul>, const Eigen::Tensor<float, 2>, Eigen::MakePointer>) (int)’
   ans = u*u.constant(v.sum()(0));
                               ^
```

as does

```
ans = u*u.constant(v.sum().eval()(0))
```

.

```
error: no match for call to ‘(const Eigen::TensorForcedEvalOp<const Eigen::TensorReductionOp<Eigen::internal::SumReducer<float>, const Eigen::DimensionList<long int, 2ul>, const Eigen::Tensor<float, 2>, Eigen::MakePointer> >) (int)’
   ans = u*u.constant(v.sum().eval()(0));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this exchange](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=1274), you should be able to force the evaluation by assigning the result of the reduction:

```
Eigen::Tensor<float, 0> vSum = v.sum();
```

That should work with your line:

```
ans = u * u.constant(vSum);
```

The cause of this is that if you try to call the template method `constant` directly with `v.sum()` it will try to use the declared returning type as `Scalar`, which does not work. Eigen uses a lot of complex, essentially opaque types to minimize unnecessary computation and copying, but also a lot of templating too, so it is not that uncommon having to explicitly force type conversions like in this case.

Comment: I had to change `vSum` in the second line to `vSum(0)` and `u = u * vSum(0)` also worked.